# Database is not showing up in the SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a test database and I was able to see the database in SSMS and all of a sudden Its not listng my database and When I checked the mdf and ldf files they seems to be locked . I am using Sql server 2008 R2. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is it not listing it in Object Explorer or in `sys.databases`?

Comment: no. I checked it

Comment: 1. Are you on the correct instance? Make sure you are connected to appropriate instance (Named or default)

Comment: 2. What do you mean when you say, mdf and ldf locked?

Comment: yes. And also I tried using local

Comment: The `.mdf` and `.ldf` would be locked any time SQL Server has the database connected.  Maybe you should "refresh" the database list in SSMS.

Comment: ldf and mdf files in the C\MSSQL folder

Comment: Also are you sure you have permissions to the database?  Are you a sysadmin?  Is there any chance that your permissions changed?

Comment: As Max said refresh the database list. Or else most probably, someone would have detach the database. Go right click databases, click attach and choose the proper mdf and ldf and check if it works

Comment: I tried using different users including sa

Comment: Use [SysInternals "Handle" utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) to determine what process has the `.mdf` file open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just converting the part of comment to an answer so as to close this question:

It seems like someone had the database detached, because of which database was not visible and hence you were also able to view its respective mdf and ldf.

Right Click Databases-->  click Attach--> Choose the respective mdf files for the database in question.

Refresh and check , the database should be visible.